# Does deleting from a LINQ DB also delete records in other tables that have a foreign key association?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, submitchanges

So at the root of my DB, I have a table "Customer." Customer has foreign keys going to about 6-7 other tables such as Receipts, Addresses, Documents etc. If I were to delete a customer using SubmitChanges(), would that seek out all those records with the foreign key association and delete them too, or would I need to do like 6 queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only happen if you have set up your database tables to do this with cascading deletions (i.e. `on delete cascade`).

For more information please see [Insert, Update, and Delete Operations (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx):

> LINQ to SQL does not support or
>   recognize cascade-delete operations.
>   If you want to delete a row in a table
>   that has constraints against it, you
>   must either set the ON DELETE CASCADE
>   rule in the foreign-key constraint in
>   the database, or use your own code to
>   first delete the child objects that
>   prevent the parent object from being
>   deleted. Otherwise, an exception is
>   thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of cascade action do you have on those foreign key relations??

By default, most database systems (including SQL Server, which I presume you use) will not have any "ON DELETE CASCADE" or any other action - so in that case, nothing would happen.

This T-SQL query will show you your foreign key relationships and whether or not any DELETE or UPDATE referential actions have been defined:

```
SELECT
    name 'FK Constraint',
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Parent table',
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Referenced table',
    delete_referential_action ,
    delete_referential_action_desc ,
    update_referential_action ,
    update_referential_action_desc 
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys
```

If you **want** something to happen, you need to make sure those FK relations are set to use those cascading actions.

See the MSDN docs on [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx) for more details.